# Save and Cancel buttons in Save As dialog box

Tags: vba, ms-word, savefiledialog

I'm creating a macro to:

1. Ask for a "work order" number and the file to work on (OK)
2. Insert the work order number and the file text in the new doc (OK)
3. **Save the new created file in a new location and undo the changes made if the Cancel button is clicked (KO)**

My problem is when I click the "Save" button, nothing happens. The dialog box disappears but the file is not saved, the fields are not updated and the form doesn't unload (last lines). How do I deal with these buttons?

Here's what I did so far:

```
Private Sub btn_generate_Click()
    Dim dlgSave As FileDialog
    Set dlgSave = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    Dim oRegex As New regexp
    oRegex.Pattern = "^[0-9]+$"

'Check if WO is only digits
If (oRegex.Test(txt_wo) = False) Xor (txt_wo.TextLength <> 6) Then
    'Alert message
    MsgBox "The WO must be 6 digits!", vbExclamation, "Error in WO number"
    'Focus on the WO textbox + selection of the content
    txt_wo.SetFocus
    txt_wo.SelStart = 0
    txt_wo.SelLength = Len(txt_wo.Text)

'Check if path to file is filled
ElseIf txt_filePath.Text = "" Then
    'Alert message
    MsgBox "You must choose a document to reference", vbExclamation, "Missing document"
    'Focus on the "Browse"button
    btn_browse.SetFocus
Else

'Put WO after the bookmark "workorder"
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("workorder").Range.InsertAfter (" " + txt_wo.Text)

'Copy text of the chosen file after the bookmark "texttoref"
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("texttoref").Range.Select
Selection.InsertFile (txt_filePath)

'Open "Save as..." dialog box
With dlgSave
    .InitialFileName = "eRef" + txt_wo.Text + ".docx"

    'If the user clicks "Save"
    If .Show = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Undo 2
    End If
End With

Unload Form_CreateSheet
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Fields.Update
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where are you trying to save it, you're only using a SaveAs dialog picker, not instructing Save As.

Comment: If .Show = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Undo 2
    Else
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs .selecteditems(1)
        
    End If

Comment: Annnw okay I got it ! Thank you so much @Nathan_Sav ! So right now, I succeed in saving it but even if I put it in a specific folder, the file is saved in MyDocuments :/ I'll try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Is the selected item will be the file name? You should get the full path..

Comment: The selected item wasn't working. I did: With dlgSave
        .InitialFileName = "eRef" + txt_wo.Text + ".docx"
        If .Show = False Then
            ActiveDocument.Undo 2
        Else
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs (.InitialFileName)
        End If
    End With

Comment: What does .SelectedItems(1) return?

Comment: It just triggers a compilation error. Invalid use of property. I think the .SelectedItems would have worked with a File picker dlg box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone might be interested. Here is the modified part that works

```
     With dlgSave
    'Set default name of document
    .InitialFileName = "DefaultName.docx"

    If .Show = False Then
        'undo the insertions
        ActiveDocument.Undo 2
    Else
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs (.InitialFileName)
    End If
```